# GitExtension does not show up on Visual Studio 2010 Express (Windows 7)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git-extensions

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express on Windows 7.
I recently installed GitExtension and it seems to work fine (cloning and branching and what not).  I expected it to show up on Visual Studio Express when I opened VS, but it does not. 
I have searched online and found a few references to the same problem recommending to use VS Extension manager to download the Git plugin for 2010.  However, when I tried to use Extension manager on VS to access and install GitExtension plugin nothing related to Git showed up.
Any suggestions to make the GitExtension show up on VS 2010 Express on Windows 7?
Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10):

The Visual Studio Express versions in general do not support any extensions. Unless their website specifically mentions supporting Express, I would expect it only to work on the full version of Visual Studio to be honest. Extensions for the Express editions are limited to ["toolbox controls, item templates, project templates, and custom start page"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/09/building-and-publishing-an-extension-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx) - anything more than that needs the full VS to work.